# Cropping an image using openCV Matrix using Android binaries

Tags: android, opencv

I'm running into problems cropping an image using the Android OpenCV binaries.

This is what I'm doing to try to crop the upper left quadrant of the image:

```
Initialization {
    mYuv = new Mat(mFrameSize.height + mFrameSize.height / 2, mFrameSize.width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    mGraySubmat = mYuv.submat(0, mFrameSize.height, 0, mFrameSize.width);
}


processFrame(byte[] data) {
   mYuv.put(0, 0, data);
   Imgproc.cvtColor(mGraySubmat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR, 4);
   bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mFrameSize.width/2, mFrameSize.height/2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
   Rect roi = new Rect(0,0,mFrameSize.width/2,mFrameSize.height/2);
   Mat faceMat = new Mat(mRgba,roi);
   Utils.matToBitmap(faceMat.clone(), bmp);
```

}

What I get is a garbled image. I've seen other posts that say to do what I'm doing but it's not working. Actually the image looks like it's there but there are also shadow images that are out of proportion.

I can do this manually and it works file - see below. Am I doing something wrong?

```
processFrame(byte[] data) {

     for (int i = 0; i < frameSize; i++) {
     int y = (0xff & ((int) data[i]));
     rgba[i] = 0xff000000 + (y << 16) + (y << 8) + y;
}
// Example of cropping the upper left corder
bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mFrameSize.width/2, mFrameSize.height/2, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
bmp.setPixels(rgba, 0/* offset */, mFrameSize.width /* stride */, 0, 0, mFrameSize.width/2, mFrameSize.height/2);
```

Comment: The two sources are not comparable as you do not use data in the first one. Anyway the type of your bitmap and data should match.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added the missing pieces

Comment: I have upvoted your question because I could not find a working solution after the modification of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you start from [this example](http://fossies.org/unix/misc/OpenCV-2.3.1a.tar.gz/dox/Sample4View_8java_source.html). In this original source you can see that there is no `Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR` conversion. If you want to have a color image then you need to use choice two:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuv, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV420sp2RGB, 4);
```

and you do not need mGraySubmat.

If you need grayscale image then the first choice is better:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(mGraySubmat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);
```

This latter choice truncates the chrominance components of the [default preview format](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html) what is a  `YCbCr_420_SP (NV21)` formatted image.

Comment: I've used both Imgproc.COLOR_YUV420sp2RGB and Imgproc.COLOR_YUV420sp2RGB successfully for color grayscale respectively. As long as I don't try to crop the image they both work exactly as expected. The problem only comes when I use Mat faceMat = new Mat(mRgba, roi ); to crop the image. That's when the distortions come in